# How do I make a month and year pick in iOS/Phonegap

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins

[image: month and year pick]

Is this a feature one can activate? Or can someone guide me where to look?

Answer (score 0):

use Ionic FrameWork 
ionic has very good components such as datetime
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#datetime

Answer (score 0):

You want to check out Cordova/Phonegap plugins such as:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-datepicker

Or search through the listing here:

http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?platforms=cordova-ios

Answer (score 0):

take a look at input type="month" in html5. But you will probably need some extra css

Comment: sorry typed it wrong. It should be input type="month"

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your answer to include the comment you provided. For more tips on how to write a good answer, please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).